# "error: device not found" for AVD Android 5.1

Tags: android, jenkins, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to install an .apk to AVD but the process just hangs with message `- waiting for device -`.
Here's how I'm starting the emulator itself and connecting to it:

```
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-arm -no-boot-anim -ports 5851,5852 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-22_armeabi-v7a_myapp -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window -force-32bit -noaudio -gpu off
Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5851
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5851 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:5851
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5851 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:5851
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5851 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5851 logcat -v time
[android] Attempting to unlock emulator screen
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5851 shell input keyevent 82
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5851 shell input keyevent 4
[android] Emulator is ready for use (took 47 seconds)

/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5851
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5584 install -r myapp-debug-unaligned.apk
error: device not found
- waiting for device -
```

When I'm trying to run AVD for older android version, it works fine.